# List all peerID in rtmfp group

Tags: rtmfp

How can I get list of all peerID`s who now connected into rtmfp group?
Or variant get a group ID, but such as stored on the server.
I tried use sam groupspec.toString(); but this command return result not like in server. Server Cumulus.

Answer (score 0):

I assuming you're talking about ActionScript here? The RTMFP protocol in Flash is essentially a rendezvous service - meaning it helps you connect to other clients and that's it. It's not connected to a server as such so it's not aware of who's connected at any given time (and it has no need to know). The messages get passed around by the clients between themselves as opposed to the server.

Making a 'user list' is possible, as described here; http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_User_List_with_RTMFP_Groups-17535.html

Hope this helps!